# How can I use types so that generic operations are inlined (or "open coded") in sbcl?

Tags: optimization, types, common-lisp, sbcl

SBCL compiler optimizations are based on the idea that if a type is declared, then "open coding" allows generic operations to be replaced with specific ones.
For example

```
(defun add (a b)
    (declare (type fixnum a b))
    (+ a b))
```

Will allow the generic `+` to be replaced with a single instruction for fixnum.

However, I have found that in practice, this seems to rarely be possible because:

1. In order for a function to be specialized/optimized it must be inlinable. The declaration must be marked explicitly with a `(declaim (inline ...))`, so the author of a function must anticipate that others might want to inline it. (In theory the compiler could generate multiple versions, but this doesn't seem to be the case.)
2. Most standard functions do not appear inlineable.

For example, one would expect that the following declaration is sufficient for open coding to take place:

```
(defun max-integers (array)
    (declare (optimize (speed 3) (space 0) (safety 0)))
    (declare (inline reduce))
    (declare (type (simple-array fixnum (*)) array))
    (reduce (lambda (a b) (if (> b a) b a)) array))
```

However, the assembly shows it's making a function call to the generic reduce:

```
; Size: 22 bytes. Origin: #x1001BC8109
; 09:       488B15B0FFFFFF   MOV RDX, [RIP-80]                ; no-arg-parsing entry point
                                                              ; #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA
                                                              ;                # ..)>
; 10:       B904000000       MOV ECX, 4
; 15:       FF7508           PUSH QWORD PTR [RBP+8]
; 18:       B8781C3220       MOV EAX, #x20321C78              ; #<FDEFN REDUCE>
; 1D:       FFE0             JMP RAX
```

The conclusion seems to be that the compiler cannot actually do much type optimization, as each usage of `reduce`, `map`, etc is a barrier to type propagation, and they are building blocks of everything else.
How can I overcome this and take advantage of optimizations by declaring types?
I really want to avoid writing type specific versions of each function or "macroifying" what should be a function.

Comment: `(reduce #'> array)` doesn't make sense, because `#'>` returns `t` or `nil` which are not valid inputs for `#'>`.

Comment: @Svante silly me! Let me write it correctly and update the question.

Comment: @Svante I have made the correction.

Comment: There's not really much you can do to force optimizations. All you can do is declare types as much as possible, and hope that the compiler is able to use them. Some compilers are better at this than others.

Comment: @Barmar sure, I understand that CL doesn't specify how types will be used, but I am focusing on SBCL. It clearly has a lot of infrastructure built for doing optimization, my question is how I use that effectively. `reduce` is just one example to illustrate what appears to be limitations of the larger system. If there are weird reasons why my example doesn't work, but other practices will, I would be interested.

Answer (score 4):

I think one answer is that if you want to write FORTRAN-style array-bashing code, write FORTRAN-style array-bashing code.  In particular using things like `reduce` is probably not the way to do this.

For instance if you change your function to the perfectly readable

```
(defun max-integers/loop (array)
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (space 0) (safety 0))
           (type (simple-array fixnum (*)) array))
  (loop for i of-type fixnum across array
        maximizing i))
```

Then SBCL does a far, far better job of optimising it.

---

It's worth pointing out another confusion in your question:  You say that for something like

```
(defun add (a b)
  (declare (type fixnum a b))
  (+ a b))
```

SBCL will optimize `+` to the machine instruction.  No, it won't.  The reason it won't is because the `fixnum` type is not closed under addition: consider what `(add most-positive-fixnum 1)` should do.  If you want to generate very fast code for integers you need to make sure that your integer types are small enough that the compiler can be sure that the operations you're doing on them remain machine integers (or, if you want to live dangerously, cover your code with `(the fixnum ...)` and set `safety` to `0` when compiling, which seems to allow the compiler to just return the wrong answer for addition in the way people usually expect computers to do).

Comment: Thanks. In the mean time I found and tested this sample: https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/756926 in which `replace` is inlined as I would have expected. So it looks like there are reasonable transforms for many system functions, and as you said, map/reduce is probably just not a good fit for this. The key thing I want to verify is that the pattern of declaring generic functions as inlineable, and then ensuring types are declared by the caller will allow optimization to take place, which appears to be true.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: you almost certainly won't need to declare the system functions inline: the compiler will do that.  The useful declaration would `notinline` in fact, if you wanted to be able to see the function call.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force the implementation to open-code functions that weren't declared `INLINE` when they were defind -- it simply hasn't saved the information needed.

However, the overhead of calling `REDUCE` is probably negligible compared to the actual processing. So what you *can* do is declare the types of `a` and `b`, to optimize the callback function.

```
(reduce (lambda (a b) (declare (type fixnum a b)) (if (> b a) b a)) array)
```

I guess you were hoping that if it open-coded `reduce` it would automatically propagate this type from the declaration of `array`, so you wouldn't need to do this.

Comment: Yes, precisely I had hoped that would be propogated. Is there any guidance either for the CL standard, or the SBCL implementation itself that specifies which functions are inlinable?

Comment: Sorry, no. Optimizations are left entirely to "quality of implementation". Implementations are allowed to ignore INLINE completely. All these declarations are just considered to be hints that the implementation can use if it wants to.

Comment: I don't know SBCL-specific optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for your help, perhaps this is an SBCL mailing list question. Yeah I don't imagine the call to reduce is expensive, but there are all sorts of iteration and lookup optimizations that are being left off the table, because it cannot "see" that it is a simple array.